# How can I change the theme of the main page for the website to my own design by using the Bluehost?

Tags: wordpress, bluehost

I am new to the web design, and I using the Bluehost. My question is I want to change the theme that the Bluehost had given to me for the main page to my own design.

So, when I bought the plan for the Bluehost, and they had asked me to set up what I want to have for my website. Then there had few choices for "Blog" and "Professional", and I don't know what is the difference between both of them. Then I had chosen the Blog selection, but it looks not want I want to have. Because I want to use my own design for the pages, not using their themes for my website.

What I want to have is that I don't want to have a blog for my website, and I want to write the HTML, CSS, and javascript codes and design the page by myself, then upload it to the Bluehost for my website.

So, how can I change the theme of the blog from Bluehost's system to my own design, I don't want to use their themes that had given. Then how can I upload my code's folder to the Bluehost to design my own page, and I didn't find where I can upload the folder to the Bluehost.

Can someone help me with these problems?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, have you spoken to Bluehost support to see if they're able to change this for you?

Comment: Not yet, I will ask them later. Thanks